# fetching json object by ajax in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

guys i am new so please help me .. i am trying to fetch a json data by using jqyery ajax in jsp .. but it is not working .. undefined appears .. here is my code
in servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    JSONObject json = null;
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter(); 

    try {
        json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("key1", "value1");
        json.put("key2", "value2");
        json.put("key3", "value3");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    pw.print(json.toString());
    pw.close(); 
}
```

in jsp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({

        url : 'Server',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        error : function(that,e) {

            console.log(e);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data.json);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What's the parse error?

Comment: @bmarkham i dont know .. the console says parse error

Comment: @bmarkham what is your suggestions ??

Comment: I would check if the json is actually being sent to whatever url you have

Comment: @bmarkham ok ... just let me know .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use,

```
 response.getWriter().write(jsonStr); 
 response.flushBuffer();
```

so by response you get the `json` string itself

ie:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

JSONObject json = null;
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter(); 

try {
    json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("key1", "value1");
    json.put("key2", "value2");
    json.put("key3", "value3");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
    response.flushBuffer();  //flush the written json string 
    pw.close(); 
}
```

Comment: it prints [object object]

Comment: that's receiving side ajax will convert to JSON Object , so you parse the object get the value 
eg: 
on the success u can try data.key1 to get the key1 value

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `doGet(request, response)` within your `doPost` method. it may be writing to the response.

Additionally, what happens within the network tab of your console?

Comment: now "undefined" is poping out .. what is the solution for this ??